# How to test quasar component with cypressjs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, cypress, quasar-framework

I use quasar to build my webapp and I have question regarding testing components with CypressJS.

I am using https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#Example--Generating-multiple-values on my webapp and that looks as the following:

[image]

and the component code:

```
<q-select
  filled
  label="Enter your interests"
  new-value-mode="add-unique"
  v-model="user_interests"
  use-chips
  multiple
  option-value="id"
  option-label="description"
  input-debounce="0"
  :options="interests_filtered"
  @remove="interestRemoved"
  @filter="filterInterests"
  style="width: 400px"
/>
```

I would like to write a test for `q-select` for instance, if the component `q-select` contains any values.

My question is, how to write such a test with CypressJS?

Comment: What seems to be an issue? Do you want to render this component and test it in isolation, or do you want to do e2e test?

Comment: I would like to do e2e test with cypressjs.

Comment: What did you try? With what exactly do you have a problem? Have you read the Cypress docs?

Comment: The question is, how to do it correctly? What I need is advices?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Folder-Structure

Answer (score -1):

Give your `q-select` component an id attribute first:

```html
<q-select id="select"></q-select>
```

Get the component with the id, click it and check for span elements containing your desired option and click it as well.

```js
cy.get("select").click()
cy.get("span").contains("LABEL_OF_OPTION").click()
```

Not quite perfect, but is an approach worth.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the targets, here I post my suggestion:

Search input use:

```
<q-select search-id-attr />
```

Dialog list items use:

```
<q-select>
<template v-slot:option="scope">
<q-item search-select-attr v-bind="scope.itemsProps">
<q-item-section>
<q-item-label>{{scope.opt.yourProperty}}</q-item-label>
</q-item-section>
</q-item>
</template>
</q-select>
```